# Remap context menu key to a Fn key (for brightness control shortcut)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-surface-pro-3, button-remapping

I recently upgraded from a Microsoft Type Cover 3 to a TC 4. It is definitely a vast improvement but I miss the right handed function key, as it previously allowed me to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>/<kbd>Del</kbd> screen brightness shortcut with one hand.

Does anyone have a solution to this? I am essentially looking for either a way to change the new context menu key (to the right of the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key) to a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I can still use the <kbd>Fn toggle</kbd> key on the Type Cover 4, but it is much more awkward than having a function key on the same side as the backspace/delete keys.

I would also be content with being able to, say, remap those brightness adjustment shortcuts to <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> through autohotkey or something like that, I just am not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a Type Cover but generally the Fn key doesn't generate a scan code, so you can't do anything with it, remap it to another key or vice versa